# How to remove content database read only state in failover servers with log shipping

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

We have SP2013 environment with DR servers enabled with Log shipping and content databases set to read only mode.
Now we want to enable the DR sites to Read and Write mode.

So is it standard process to set the databases to remove read-only mode in SQL server management studio or through below PowerShell in failover servers with log shipping enabled.

**Powershell script**

```
$Admin = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteAdministration(‘http://weburl/sites/sitecollectionurl’)   
$Admin.ClearMaintenanceMode()
```

Thanks

Comment: what type of dr you have? separate Sharepoint farm? or SQL mirroring etc?